# How to store curve to database

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, database-design

I would like to ask how to store curve to DB. Curve object is represented by an array of points.

***I have two options:***

**1) create two tables one for curve one for points**

- it would look something like this: `CURVE[id]`, `POINT[id, x, y, order, curve_id]`
- I am not sure if this is optimal, to get one curve from database I would need to join to tables and in the POINT table there would be a lot of points

**2) one curve = one row in one table**

- I would store all data in one table for example like this: CURVE[id, data] where data could be in formate "[[1,2],[2,2],[3,4] ...]" (string) or as blob or something like that.

What do you think? Is there any other option?

Comment: In this case, i would store the data either in binary or as varchar. Since there is no real use case to actually query the points, it makes no sense to normalize them.

Comment: So you are suggesting something I proposed, to store is for example as varchar (string) "{[1,2], [2,3] ...}"? Does anyone here know how to implemented this using spring boot and its repository?

Comment: Does your database support arrays, if so, consider storing as an array.

Comment: So I briefly checked the possibilities of PostgeSQL and it allows arrays but I am using the hibernate ORM framework for java and JPA and I would like to stay database independent (to be able to change the database in future) so I don't want to use some features which are typical only for some databases. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use javax.persistence.AttributeConverter and create curve converter like this:

```
public class CurveConverter implements AttributeConverter<Curve, String> {
private static final String SEPARATOR1 = ",";
private static final String SEPARATOR2 = ";";


@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Curve curve) {
    if (curve == null) {
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(CurvePoint curvePoint:curve.getPoints()){
        sb.append(curvePoint.getTorque());
        sb.append(SEPARATOR1);
        sb.append(curvePoint.getSpeed());
        sb.append(SEPARATOR2);
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - SEPARATOR2.length());

    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public Curve convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    if (dbData == null || dbData.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] pieces = dbData.split(SEPARATOR2);

    if (pieces == null || pieces.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    List<CurvePoint> curvePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String piece:pieces){
        String[] numbers = piece.split(SEPARATOR1);
        curvePoints.add(new CurvePoint(Float.parseFloat(numbers[0]), Float.parseFloat(numbers[1])));
    }

    return Curve.builder().points(curvePoints).build();
}
}
```

which will store your curve as string (CSV - "1.1,2.2;3.3,4.4 ...") to table as one attribute. You will get rid of joints and it will be faster. This is only good when the curve is immutable (all points are changing at once)

Then you just add annotation on field in entity where the curve is used like this:

```
@Column(name = "curve", length = 10000)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Convert(converter = CurveConverter.class)
Curve curve;
```

Important here is to set correct length of the string. Also check that `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` is used to load the curve data lazy (only when we need them). The annotation `@Convert(converter = CurveConverter.class)` then says to hibernate that before saving this field to database it will be converted using our newly created curve CurveConvertor (same when we will get the data from DB).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store your data points in separated row, you need only an additional index to order them.
You can recreate the string you proposed with the use of `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.
Your **table** would have the following **structure**:

- curve_id
- point_id
- x_coord
- y_coord

The querying would look like:

```sql
--- {[1,2], [2,3] ...}
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS("[", x_coord, ",", y_coord, "]"))
FROM table
WHERE curve_id ORDER BY point_id
```

Comment: I probably wrote it not correctly, I don't need the points in this format "{[1,2], [2,3] ...}".  I was suggesting this string just to save some calculation for database (it would not need to join all the points)

Comment: What you are recommending is to have one table for curve with additional data and this table would point to multiple points which would have x and y coordinate? Something like TABLE[curve_id, name, ..., point_id] different table for point TABLE[point_id,x_c,y_c,order_index]? Did I understood correctly?

Comment: I would say one table for your curves (with the curve_id to distinguish your different curves)

Comment: So how would you store all the points in the curve table. Maybe you already tried to explain it to me in original post but I am not sure I get it. Could you try to describe it more precisely. Thank you so much. Sometimes it is rough with me :)

Comment: See data structure of the table. Let's take a sample. curve_id = 1 and 3 points (1: (0,1), 2: (1,5), 3: (3:2)) (point_id: (x_coord, y_coord))

Comment: This is what I have right now table CURVE[id, point_id] and than another table with points POINTS[id, x_coord, y_coord, order_nuber], the order number is there to keep the order of point in the curve. So you think this is good solution and there is no problem that I have to join so many points to one curve am I right?

Comment: Join the points is not an issue, but if you have no additional metadata about the curve, I would recommend all in one table.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the curve points in a single attribute with JSON datatype.